# Pagination Icons - Where to find

Tags: pagination

I tried a jqgrid fiddle code which works perfect. But is there any way I can download the same set of icons that the pagination shows in it ?
Below is the fiddle link

In the jquery-ui.css I find the styles like

```
.ui-icon-search 
.ui-icon-seek
.ui-icon-next


[enter link description here][1]
```

If that is not downloadable where can I find similar icons ?

Thanks

Update
I tried the same fiddle as a separate page where I see the icons. But When I try integrating the same in my web page, I don't see the images.

Answer (score 0):

Font Awesome is a good iconic font and CSS toolkit.

https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/

The search icon: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/search/